# symfony3 pass variable to parent template

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

How is it possible to pass a var from a controller to the parent template (base.html.twig)?
I already have a return statement in my controller to a page named login and tried to just add another return statement with my var, like this:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
return $this->render('login.html.twig');
return $this->render('base.html.twig', array('session'=>$session));
```

But I get the error, that session is not defined, when I'm reloading the page.

I want to use the session parameter for an ajusted navigation after loging in.
Thanks in advance, hope someone can help :)

update:
Here are my templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Die 3 Meta-Tags oben *müssen* zuerst im head stehen; jeglicher sonstiger head-Inhalt muss *nach* diesen Tags kommen -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap-CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="{{ asset('css/grund.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />



    <!-- Nur für Testzwecke. Kopiere diese Zeilen nicht in echte Projekte! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- Unterstützung für Media Queries und HTML5-Elemente in IE8 über HTML5 shim und Respond.js -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{path('homepage')}}">Test-Projekt</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             {% if session is null %}
            <li><a href="{{path('homepage')}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{path('anmelden')}}">Anmelden</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{path('logout')}}">Abmelden</a></li>
            {{% endif %}}
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
 </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
    <!-- Bootstrap-JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Am Ende des Dokuments platziert, damit Seiten schneller laden -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10-Anzeigefenster-Hack für Fehler auf Surface und Desktop-Windows-8 -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's my login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Anmeldung{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h1 class="page-header">Anmeldung</h1>
    {% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')}}</div>
{% endif %}
    <div class='well' id='logindiv'>
        <form action="{{ path('anmelden') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="_username" class="control-label" id="lblname">Benutzername:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="_password" class="control-label" id="lblpwd">Passwort:</label>
            <input type="password" id="passwort" name="_password" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" value="/homepage" name="_target_path" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">anmelden</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is what my navigation looks like rendered:
[image]

Comment: Stop and look at your code for a moment.  What do you think a return statement does?  What do you think happens to code following a return statement?  And on a different topic, base.html.twig will be included from your login html.  Go back to the template chapter in the docs and read though again.  Consider implementing the examples until things sink in.

Comment: Please, paste here templates content. You need a block in you parent template and then you can overwrite it in child one.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an apostrope, look:

```
return $this->render('base.html.twig, array('session'=>$session));
```

Compared to

```
return $this->render('base.html.twig', array('session'=>$session));
```

Comment: possibly pass the session to the child twig file instead? It should be available as far as I'm aware

Comment: I already tried to pass the variable to a twig-file that extends the base.html.twig if that's what you mean and it sadly didn't work...